# Extracting the GPG userid from the Public key file?

Tags: privacy, pgp, audit, gnupg

Is it possible to extract userid from GPG public key?

I got public key only and want to know to whom it might belong. I find one possible workaround — to publish this information on keyserver — it decodes information and reveals it to public. But I'm not sure, I should do this.

Is it possible to extract userid using command line `gpg`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `gpg --list-packets [filename]` to list all data packets, then grep for user IDs. For example:

```
$ gpg --export 0xDED9B508F4E10DB2 | gpg --list-packets | Egrep '^:user ID packet'
:user ID packet: "John Doe <john@example.org>"
```

An alternative would be to use `pgpdump`

```
$ gpg --export 0xDED9B508F4E10DB2 | pgpdump | Egrep '^[[:space:]]*User ID'
    User ID - John Doe <john@example.org>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following will emit the "username < email >" field from the UID packet, without requiring regexes:

```
$ gpg --with-colons --list-keys 0xDED9B508F4E10DB2 | awk -F: '$1=="uid" { print $10 }'
blah <a@b>
```